# getting configurationRefresher as null

Tags: c#, azure, azure-app-configuration

I am using azure app configuration with azure function. So i want to refresh the keys automatically but i am getting configurationRefresher as null always.

```
 builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(appConfigurationOptions =>
            {
                appConfigurationOptions
                    .Select(ConfigurationKeys.AZURE_FUNC_TEST)
                    .Select(KeyFilter.Any, environment.EnvironmentName)
                    .ConfigureRefresh(refreshOptions =>
                    {
                        refreshOptions.Register(ConfigurationKeys.AZURE_FUNC_TEST, true);
                        refreshOptions.SetCacheExpiration(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
                    })
                    .UseFeatureFlags(flagOptions =>
                    {
                        flagOptions.Label = environment.EnvironmentName;
                        flagOptions.CacheExpirationInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                    })
                    .GetRefresher();
                configurationRefresher = appConfigurationOptions.GetRefresher();
            },true);
            return builder;
```

I found the reason why it is null actually i have the above code in a helper class and then i am passing the above result to the startup class and then in startup class it builds. Hence i am not getting value. But is there any way to get the value in startup class and above code i want it in helper class

Answer (score 0):

The `AddAzureAppConfiguration` method takes a delegate as input. This delegate runs only when `Build` method is invoked on the `ConfigurationBuilder` instance.

In order to get the `configurationRefresher` instance initialized in your helper class, you could invoke the `ConfigurationBuilder.Build` method to get an instance of `IConfiguration`. This instance could then be registered in the dependency injection container.

```cs
IConfiguration configuration = builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(appConfigurationOptions =>
{
    appConfigurationOptions
        .Select(ConfigurationKeys.AZURE_FUNC_TEST)
        .Select(KeyFilter.Any, environment.EnvironmentName)
        .ConfigureRefresh(refreshOptions =>
        {
            refreshOptions.Register(ConfigurationKeys.AZURE_FUNC_TEST, true);
            refreshOptions.SetCacheExpiration(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        })
        .UseFeatureFlags(flagOptions =>
        {
            flagOptions.Label = environment.EnvironmentName;
            flagOptions.CacheExpirationInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        })
        .GetRefresher();

    configurationRefresher = appConfigurationOptions.GetRefresher();
}, true);

return configuration;
```